# Density function evaluation probability

Tags: probability

Can anyone help to tell me if this is how you would do the following;[image]

I calculated that $k=6$, for b I got $0.7407$, and for c I got $E[Y]=0.5$ while for d I got $V[Y]=0.05$

But I dont know if I am did the question correct or completely wrong. Would anyone mind please letting me know?

Comment: Your $k$ is correct (haven't checked the others). But how did you obtain $b$ (what did you compute)? (besides the correctness, the method should also be given, at least to your teacher)

Comment: The numerical answers are all correct. Particularly in case some were or might be wrong, it would have been useful if you had indicated your procedure. Also for b) $20/27$ is more informative than $0.7407$.

Comment: @ClementC. Thanks, but it is not homework it is from past exam. ( which Is why right now I just want to know the numeric)

Comment: @PersonaA Then yes, your answers are correct.